# Missing passes in .exr?

Tags: file-format, .exr

I rendered a multichannel .exr with a bunch of passes but when I import it back into Blender I lose two of the passes.

I checked in Nuke and the passes are visible there but not in Blender. The missing passes on the file are Diffuse Direct and Diffuse Indirect. Is the file hiding them somewhere in Blender?

Preview of passes available in Blender vs Nuke:

[image: blender exr]
[image: nuke exr]

exr file: http://www.filedropper.com/popcorn

Comment: Can confirm, both passes are available in nuke. [Please report this as bug](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/2/).

Comment: Looks like there is a bug report here: https://developer.blender.org/T48466

Comment: If possible, please take the time and report it again. Otherwise I'll do it, just let me know.

Comment: New report: https://developer.blender.org/T49607

Comment: Just a heads up I'm using version 2.77a and haven't upgraded yet, this error may have been fixed in the new version.

Comment: I've tested your file with 2.78...

Comment: Just a note: If a file was originally saved in 2.77a or previous, import the image again in 2.78+ to enable the missing passes.